# How can I continuously write data to a text file?

Tags: c#, datetime, streamwriter

Every second I just want to write the DateTime(HH:mm:ss) and a `0` or `1` as a line in a text file.

`0` appears if the received data does not contain `UCAST` and `=g`, if this is true, then I want to write the `DateTime` and `1`. It's the `DateTime` where the message is received.

My problem is that I only get the `DateTIme` and `1`, but never get `DateTime` and `0`. The line is always replaced by the new `DateTime` and `1`, so the old one doesn't exist any longer.

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        recievdata = SerialPort.ReadExisting();
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));

        using (Stream stream2 = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        using (StreamWriter sWriter1 = new StreamWriter(stream2))
        {
            if (recievdata.Contains("UCAST") && recievdata.Contains("=g"))
            {
                sWriter1.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                sWriter1.Write(" ; ");
                sWriter1.WriteLine(1);
                if (SleepMovChar.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    SleepMovChar.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    { SleepMovChar.Series["Bevægelse"].Points.AddXY(xValue = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), 1); }));
                    SleepMovChar.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sWriter1.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                sWriter1.Write(" ; ");
                sWriter1.WriteLine(0);
                timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Specifying FileMode.OpenOrCreate opens the file at the beginning so everytime you write to the file you are overwriting the existing contents. Open with FileMode.Append

Comment: Thanks it helped.
Can you tell me, why it only show the dateTime and 1, never shows me 0.
At the time it doesn't receive the string "UCAST" && "-g" it should write down datetime and 0.

Comment: I think `FileMode.Append` will do the job as already suggested but as a side note, you should not open and close file rapidly as this event is expected to raise whenever the data receives. Open file once, then find some other event handle to close file when you are done.

Comment: Maybe you should make it output `recievdata` too instead of just the DateTime, so you can figure out why it's always entering the first branch. Or debug it with a breakpoint...

Comment: The only reason the code would never write "; 0" to the file instead of "; 1" is that the data being read never fails to contain the text you're looking for. Without a better code example, nothing more can be said about that. Other thoughts: you should just open the file once (outside of this method), with FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, and FileShare.Read; you probably don't want to subscribe to `Tick` every time you write "; 0"; and `ReadExisting()` without additional logic to ensure you've read a complete sequence of data, that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I found out what was wrong, and now it works properly. :-)